# Special characters change when exporting django

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-import-export

I'm using django import export package and MySQL for the database. Everything works fine, except for one thing. When I exported, the data that has "special characters" changed. For example **Château** will be changed to **ChÃ¢teau**. Even though, everything is displayed correctly in the admin.

How can I fix this? Any solutions? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I've deleted all the django import export and tried to create a simple export function, but the result is the same. Here is the code:

```
def export(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['vineyard', 'name', 'email1', 'email2', 'address', 'website', 'web_text', 'number'])

    for x in Example.objects.all().values_list('vineyard', 'name', 'email1', 'email2', 'address', 'website', 'web_text', 'number'):
        writer.writerow(x)

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="members.csv"'

    return response
```

Here is the models.py:

```
class VineyardUser(models.Model):
    vineyard = models.OneToOneField(Vineyard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    email1 = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    email2 = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    web_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vineyard.name + " - " + self.name
```

Comment: Can you add code where you're specifying your `ModelResource`? Also, the code of your models.py.

Comment: Actually, i've deleted all the django import export things and tried to create a simple export function by myself. and the result is the same. I believe that the problem is on the database but I don't know how to fix that. I will edit my question @vinkomlacic

Comment: Might be, also, what are you exporting it to and how are you viewing the exported data?

Comment: So you're exporting it to csv. You sure the editor where you're looking at the output supports UTF-8?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure .. but how can I make it supports UTF-8? @vinkomlacic

Comment: Can't tell you without knowing what are you using. But, try using different editors and see if the problem is the same

Comment: What do you mean by "editors"? @vinkomlacic

Comment: What do you use to look at the exported CSV file? Which program?

Comment: on linux you can use: `file <filename>` to output the encoding